# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. Push in some folder executes related stage

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have repository for `C` learners. My goal is when someone push some code, this code will be tested. I have several folders in my repo - each folder for each assignment. For now when someone pushes i can bulid and test all assignment in all folders. I want to test only assignment that was pushed.
For example:

I have 3 folders in my repo:

```
-Task1
-Task2
-Task3
```

When someone pushes i build all tasks and test them all.

What i want: if someone push only Task1, then i want to compile and test only Task1 and not whole repo. Is this possible? Tell me if i need to give more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible using the [only:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) feature of Gitlab CI. You can specify a directory in which changes would trigger the job.
Example:

```
task_1_test:
  script: <compile & run test for this directory>
  only:
    changes:
      - Task1/*.{c,cc,cpp,o,h}
```

The job would then trigger by default on a push event which contains a commit with changes to files with the extensions c,cc,cpp,o,h in the directory Task1.

Hope this helps